# Hdfs blocksize defaults to 128 mb when using java api

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I wonder is the following behaviour is as it should be (hadoop 2.1.0-beta):

I changed the dfs.blocksize to 64m in hdfs-site.xml. If I upload a file via `hdfs dfs -put src dst` the blocksize is correctly shown as 64mb (in the webinterface). However, if I use the java api (here via scala), the blocksize for the file is 128mb (default).

I don't have the configuration files in the classpath of my application, because I expected that the namenode should be aware of it's blocksize. Here is how I use the java api:

```
val hdfsConf = new Configuration()
hdfsConf.set("fs.defaultFS", hdfsAddress)
FileSystem.get(hdfsConf)
...
val delSource = false; val overWrite = false
fs.copyFromLocalFile(delSource, overWrite, new Path(localPath), new Path(destinationPath))
```

Is my namenode configured wrongly, so that it does not apply the correct blocksize? Or is this expected behaviour?

Addition: This is how I start my namenode:

```
hadoop-2.1.0-beta/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh --config /home/andre/experiments/suts/hadoop-2.1.0-beta/conf --script hdfs start namenod
```

The hdfs-site.xml is in the specified folder and has this property in it:

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.blocksize</name>
  <value>64m</value>
</property>
```

I didn't specify $HADOOP_CONF_DIR, because I switch between multiple hadoop installations on this machine (and I hope and don't think it is necessary).

Comment: The block size is determined in the client side. When you create a file, the client will calculate the block size (if you do not set, it will be the default value) and tell the namenode. So if you use any configuration files in your java application, it should be the default value.

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense, although I think it would be also intuitive that the namenode decides about the blocksize.So if I understood correctly, the command "hdfs dfs -put ..." only works because this client is aware of the config dir?

Comment: Sorry for my typo. The correct is "if you do not use any configuration files in your java application, it should be the default value." If you use "hdfs dfs -put", hadoop will find the config dir by itself.

Answer (score 0):

first load the data in hdfs thru customized hdfs size (not default 128mb) then when you you will access that thru java then you will get correct size.

hadoop fs -D dfs.block.size=16777216 -put  .